# mysql query order by two column with weight for each of them

Tags: php, mysql, rating, rating-system

I have table `Foo(id, name, rateAvg, rateNum)`. `rateAvg` is between 1 to 5 and `rateNum` is number of rates by users.

I  query table with mysql and order them by most rated Foos like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Fooo ORDER BY rateAVG DESC, rateNum DESC
```

but that is not fair enough, for example one row has rateAvg of 4.8 with 1000 rates and the other with rateAvg of 5 and 10 rates and by my query item two come first.

Edit:
by comment of @kingkero I found out that each of rateAvg and rateNum should have some weight for ordering, how can apply that in my query

Comment: This is a tough question I'm afraid not one fit for Stack Overflow. It all depends on how you define "fair". You could use the number of ratings as a weight but that the impact of that needs to be tweaked for your individual application

Comment: This is a design question, not a programming one. It is really up to you how you weigh number of ratings and average rating to produce your list. The simplest solution is to multiply the 2 numbers with each other to get a score and use this score to order your results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to apply a [`bayesian average`](http://www.lifewithalacrity.com/2005/12/collective_choi.html), but you should pre calculate this rating and store in one of your fields.

```
b(r) = [ W(a) * a + W(r) * r ] / (W(a) + W(r)]

r = average rating for an item
W(r) = weight of that rating, which is the number of ratings
a = average rating for your collection
W(a) = weight of that average, which is an arbitrary number,
       but should be higher if you generally expect to have more ratings
       for your items; 100 is used here, for a database which expects
       many ratings per item
b(r) = new bayesian rating
```

For example in your case:

```
a = (4.8 * 1000 + 5 * 10) / 1010 = 4.8019
r1 = 4.8
r2 = 5
W(a) = 100 // arbitrary average weight
W(r1) = 1000 // weight of first raiting
W(r2) = 10 // weight of second rating

b(r1) = (100 * 4.8019 + 1000 * 4.8) / (100 + 1000) = 4.8001
b(r2) = (100 * 4.8019 + 10 * 5) / (100 + 10) = 4.8199
```

So you can see that these values are close to each other and you can try to change average weight to setup this `bayesian average rating` for your case.